# Looking for numbers with letters

Tags: python, string, pandas, int

I want to select a DataFrame column, iterate over it and select only the the numbers, and to replace the numbers that contains letters and other sings with 'Unknow'. I've tried isreal() method but it didn't work. Is there a way to acomplish this task without a function?

```
%matplotlib inline
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file = 'C:/Users/Сынкетру/Desktop/attacks.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', encoding='ISO-8859-1') 


df_clean = df.Age.dropna()

def age(number):
    try:
        number = df.isreal()
    except ValueError:
        number = 'Unknown'

map(age, df_clean)
print(d)
```

Comment: Possibly the`isnumeric()` method would work? [Example of isnumeric()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm)

Comment: Can you show what the data actually looks like as it matters here. For instance are the types always strings?

Comment: If the type is string then you can just do `df_clean.loc[~df_clean.str.isdigit()] = 'unknown'` but you may need to convert the dtype first `df_clean = df_clean.astype(str)`

Comment: The types are strings and floats. I've tried isnumeric() but it didn't work. It gives "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'"

Comment: No!  There is not a way to accomplish this without a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['1', 2, '_3', '4.', 'hello', 3.14]))

df['A'] = np.where(pd.to_numeric(df.A, 'coerce').notnull(), df.A, 'unknown')
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df.Age[~df.Age.apply(np.isreal)] = "unknown"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.